# Error with cabal build using plutus-starter-devcontainer on macOS Big Sur

Tags: plutus, haskell, nix

I'm working to set up the plutus-starter-devcontainer integration with VSCode.

Dev Environment:

- macOS Big Sur 11.5.2
- Docker Desktop 4.0.0

Following the instructions from here: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-starter

Running on a new machine without GHC or Stack installed, I created `~/.cabal/packages` directory on my machine.

After running a `cabal update`, the `cabal build` command generates the following error:

```
cabal: Failed to build prettyprinter-configurable-0.1.0.0 (which is required
by test:plutus-example-projects-test from plutus-starter-0.1.0.0 and
exe:plutus-starter-pab from plutus-starter-0.1.0.0). The failure occurred
during the configure step. The exception was:
dieVerbatim: user error (cabal:
'/nix/store/3jdnjxxb855s6q7n01d7p3ivzr1l36r9-ghc-shell-for-packages-ghc-8.10.4.20210212-env/bin/ghc'
exited with an error:
/nix/store/qvv5y4fx4x879rbsbs4g27mypl9wxbb9-gcc-wrapper-10.3.0/bin/ld: line
256: 9581 Killed
/nix/store/hy3lz2vfv9qq2v5jz9nzlx6mmiaq79rj-binutils-2.35.1/bin/ld
${extraBefore+"${extraBefore[@]}"} ${params+"${params[@]}"}
${extraAfter+"${extraAfter[@]}"}
collect2: error: ld returned 137 exit status
`cc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
)
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: My suggestion would be to report a bug in https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/issues

Comment: Thanks @kolam. This issue went away after updating to VSCode 1.60.0 and increasing the Docker Memory resource limit to 6GB.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was resolved by updating VSCode to August 2021 release (v1.60.0) and increasing Docker Memory to 6GB.